# Is there a way to use Sorbet without adding the # type annotation to every file?

Tags: sorbet

I want to start using Sorbet for my Ruby on Rails project, but I've been asked not to add the type annotation to every file.

Is there a way to use Sorbet without adding the annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Sorbet supports `--typed-override` feature where you can give sorbet a YAML file to specify what files should go into what level: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/master/test/cli/override-typed.
`srb` runner doesn't currently know about it, but there has been chatter in the community about adding support for it: https://sorbet-ruby.slack.com/archives/CHN2L03NH/p1563404308018500

Note that from our experience at Stripe we found that having `typed: true` sigils in typed files has a lot of value as it allows users to build & verify their expectations on what is typed and what is not.