# Configure Sorbet to treat all files without comment as if they had a typed: ignore comment

Tags: ruby, sorbet

My question is related to this one [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099664/is-there-a-way-to-use-sorbet-without-adding-the-type-annotation-to-every-file) but I'm ok with adding type comments to the files that have type annotations. We just don't want to have auto generated comments on hundreds of files although nothing else happened in the files. Is there a way to configure Sorbet to work like this?

Answer (score 1):

You might go a long way by using the following Sorbet flags:

```sh
$ srb tc --help
Typechecker for Ruby
Usage:
  sorbet [OPTION...] <path 1> <path 2> ...
...
      --ignore string           Ignores input files that contain the given
                                string in their paths (relative to the input
                                path passed to Sorbet). Strings beginning with /
                                match against the prefix of these relative
                                paths; others are substring matchs. Matches must
                                be against whole folder and file names, so
                                `foo` matches `/foo/bar.rb` and `/bar/foo/baz.rb`
                                but not `/foo.rb` or `/foo2/bar.rb`.
...
      --typed-override filepath.yaml
                                Yaml config that overrides strictness levels
                                on files (default: "")
...
```

If all the files you want to ignore are in a folder together or can be matched by some path matches, then a few `--ignore` lines in your `sorbet/config` file should do what you want.

Otherwise, you could use the typed overrides from a YAML file to make Sorbet interpret the files you want as `typed: ignore`. You should, again, be able to add this flag to your `sorbet/config` file.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://sorbet.org/docs/static):

> # typed: false is the **default** for files without sigils.

So the behaviour you desire should already be in place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I had a type in the title, it should in fact be `typed: ignore` instead of `typed: false`. I understand that the description in the question wasn't sufficient to clarify this on its own. I've updated the question's title accordingly.

Comment: Based on your description, `typed: false` as default for no-sigil-files  should be reasonable. Sorbet won't touch these files and only check things like missing constants or typos.

`typed: ignore` is very restrictive and most likely something you only want to use in the rare case you want to hide some code from sorbet. The team even recommend having no ignored files.